# Using PHP to split a string

Tags: php

How to split a string using php and store into three different array ?
I'm quite new to php so please give me a detail answer if you can~

Input would be a string we don't know how long it is:

```
ubuntu1204gui Client myurl/token=something1 windows7 Gateway myurl/token=token=something2 ubuntu1204gui Server myurl/token=token=something3 ...
```

and out put should be three array:

```
array1[0]= ubuntu1204gui
array1[1]= windows7
array1[2]= ubuntu1204gui
array1[3]= ...
...

array2[0]= Client
array2[1]= Gateway
array2[2]= Server
array2[3]= ...
...

array3[0]=myurl/token=token=something1
array3[1]=myurl/token=token=something2
array3[2]=myurl/token=token=something3
array3[3]=...
...
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string has 3 different types of data separated by spaces, you will need a little more than a simple explode() unfortunately.

Here is a snippet.

```
// Declare our string
$string = "ubuntu1204gui Client myurl/token=something1 windows7 Gateway myurl/token=token=something2 ubuntu1204gui Server myurl/token=token=something3";

// First Split the spring up into individual items (using the spaces as delimiter)
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
$items = explode(' ',$string);

// setup our target arrays
$array1 = $array2 = $array3 = array();

// Reindex our array to start from 1 (so we can use modulus effectively)
array_unshift($items, "temp");
unset($items[0]);

// Then we loop items & put in right array using the help of our friend modulus!
foreach($items as $key=>$item)
{
  if($key%3==0)
   $array3[] = $item;
  else
  if($key%3==2)
   $array2[] = $item;
  else
   $array1[] = $item;
}

echo'<pre>';
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
print_r($array3);
```

Tada!!

```
Array
(
    [0] => ubuntu1204gui
    [1] => Gateway
    [2] => ubuntu1204gui
)
Array
(
    [0] => Client
    [1] => windows7
    [2] => Server
)
Array
(
    [0] => myurl/token=something1
    [1] => myurl/token=token=something2
    [2] => myurl/token=token=something3
)
```

Comment: made a quick correction

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was voted down, since it does exactly what the OP wants.  It may be a messy solution, but it's a solution.

Comment: Not sure, but webarto+rob's answer is more compact/simple than mine so I will vote theirs up!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'ubuntu1204gui Client myurl/token=something1 windows7 Gateway myurl/token=token=something2 ubuntu1204gui Server myurl/token=token=something3';

$arr = [];
foreach(explode(' ', $str) as $key => $value)
{
  $arr[(($key + 1) % 3)][] = $value;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output

```
array (size=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'ubuntu1204gui' (length=13)
      1 => string 'windows7' (length=8)
      2 => string 'ubuntu1204gui' (length=13)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Client' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Gateway' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Server' (length=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'myurl/token=something1' (length=22)
      1 => string 'myurl/token=token=something2' (length=28)
      2 => string 'myurl/token=token=something3' (length=28)
```